# CV page: Incorrect sprite offsets for SO icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

[image: Wrong sprite]

I've Shift-reloaded the page multiple times, so it doesn't seem to be a caching issue at my end, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed a few weeks back. Due to the way /jobs is integrated with SO we were picking up the SO stylesheet and not using the offsets used by the /jobs stylesheet. All this was the result of adding another network site that changed the underlying sprite.